# CSV into a another workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, csv, excel

Updated question with a code that works:

I would like to be able to have one .xlsm file put csv data into a second .xlsm file using VBA for Excel. The latter file is maybe open in multible computers. Below is a code behind a button in Excel in an attempt to accomplish this:

```
Sub bad_boy()
Dim wb As Workbook, strFile As String, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\TestFolder\son1.xlsm") 'set to current worksheet name

Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

The code is supposed to enable the user to browse and choose a csv file from his/hers computer.

Comment: `ws` is defined as a worksheet, but the you give it a string. use `Set was = Workbooks.Open("MyFileName"...`

Comment: thanks for your comment ..updated question.. still doesnt work

Comment: Please indicate which line raises the error.

Comment: I note that you are also trying to set the `ws` object (a worksheet) as a `Workbook`.  This will always raise a mismatch error.

Comment: thanks David ... updated .. still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `ws` as a Worksheet object:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String
```

But you are attempting to assign it a `Workbook` object. This will always raise a mismatch error.

```
Set ws = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\TestFolder\son1.xlsm")
```

Try changing that line to:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\TestFolder\son1.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
```

Then remove the line `Set ws = ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to set a worksheet object equal to a string constant.  That is causing the error message.

Comment: thanks for your answer ..updated question.. still doesnt work